# Accordion Control: Put UserControls in Panes

Tags: c#, asp.net, accordion

I have to create an Accordion control with several panes and inside each pane I have to put a form with some textboxes, optionbutton and so on (with a Submit button) where the users can insert some values. 
Is it possible to create some user controls and put them inside the panes of my accordio?
And this solution could be the better way to follow this requisite?

Thanks a lot.

Luigi

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it.

Look at jQuery accordion plugin for example, you can find it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

Of course you can put your user controls in there and can even have them in UpdatePanels should you decide to update them separately (not the best option, but the easiest one)

Comment: I'll try with the Accordion AJAX Control Toolkit, because I don't know much jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can have use user control like below

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div>
    <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server">
        <Panes>
            <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server">
                <Content>
                    <uc:TextAndButton runat="server" />
                </Content>
            </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
            <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
                <Content>
                    <uc:TextAndButton ID="TextAndButton1" runat="server" />
                </Content>
            </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
        </Panes>
    </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try, thank you. In case of problems, I'll write to you again. Luigi